# Javascript vanilla (jquery not preferred)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, mouseevent

I'd like to know how to take this code I found here

http://jsfiddle.net/T42jj/

```
var imageGallery = [
    "http://placehold.it/350x150",
    "http://placehold.it/350x250",
    "http://placehold.it/350x350",
    "http://placehold.it/350x450"
];

var imgCount = 0; var totalImgs = imageGallery.length - 1; var timer;

function next() {
    timer = setInterval(function fn() {
        imgCount++;
        if (imgCount > totalImgs) imgCount = 0

        document.getElementById("gallery").src = imageGallery[imgCount];
        return fn;
    }(), 500)
}

function previous() {
    timer = setInterval(function fn() {
        console.log('prev')
        imgCount--;
        if (imgCount < 0) imgCount = totalImgs;
        document.getElementById("gallery").src = imageGallery[imgCount];
        return fn;
    }(), 100)
}

function stopInterval() {
    clearInterval(timer)
}

window.onmouseup = stopInterval;
```

and changing the "onMousedown" to onmouseOver so it continuously loops as you mouse over, which I've managed to do.

Then adding a stop function button that works

`onmouseClick`

```
<a href="#" onMouseover="previous(); return false;">Back</a>
<a href="#" onMouseclick="stop(); return false;">Stop</a>
```

with a Stop function breaking the loop. e.g break;

sorry i cant figure out how to format any of this. this is the worst system ever.

does this [code] work? [/code]
or something like it?

basically look at the jsfiddle code and help me if you could make a function that stops the loop from infinitely repeating images when a mouse click event occurs.

Comment: [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Four spaces indicate code. Not the best solution but there is adding JSFiddle so for bigger chunks one might choose this.

Comment: I’ve read this a few times but still don’t get it. What is the intended behaviour? In JSFiddle images change when I press buttons.